# ElasticSearch index template versioning

Tags: elasticsearch

My application creates an index template on ElasticSearch. Later on, the application is updated and needs to update the index template to support new fields.

1. Is there a way to set a some identifier for the index template
   (except its name which is always the same), such that my app can
   compare these values between the app version and the deployed
   version? (unique ID / ETag / anything else)
2. Alternatively, if I can't detect a difference: What is the cost of
   modifying the index template multiple times, mostly modifications
   that perform no actual change?
3. Can I find for an index which template it uses (and which version of it,
   if such ability exists)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use ElasticSearch's template versioning feature by including `"version": <version number>` in your template.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#versioning-templates

2. There's no cost in modifying the template, as it's just stored in ES's database {read as 'storage used by ES'}. The only difference is that updates to the templates will only be applicable to the new index being created and won't be applied to the existing indices.

Comment: Nice! This answer works on ElasticSearch version 5.0 or higher (released a year after I asked this question :) )

Comment: I see. Just saw the date posted :)

Answer (score 2):

When creating an index template, you can use the mapping metadata to store the extra info needed to know from which version of the application the mapping was created.

```
PUT _template/my_template
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "mappings" : {
      "logs" : {
        "_meta" : {
          "product" : "my_product",
          "version" : "1.0.1"
        },
        "_source" : {"enabled" : "true"},
        "properties" : {
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Then query for existing indices to find the index last created and then get its mappings.

```
GET logstash-2015.10.08/_mapping
```

You'll find the mappings and the metadata inside.

This can be useful to store the version of the product the mapping correlates to.

Comment: Excellent answer! Just what I needed for an automated index mapping update

Answer (score 0):

I've solved for this before by using version numbers, build IDs or time stamps as part of the index name (and using *index aliases* to point to the relevant index for each application).

See this post for a more detailed example:  https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is an interesting article. The indexes themselves are formatted as `logstash-2015.08.31` in my case, so no need to change their names as I am only adding new fields. The problem is detecting a difference between the deployed index template and the one that exists in my application code.

Comment: I don't know of the Elasticsearch equivalent to a database migration tool.  Since you can retrieve the current mapping from ES, it would be possible to build something like this.  Let me know what you come up with.

Comment: Perhaps the simple solution would just be a regression test that produces the latest application mapping json, and then requests the latest mapping json from Elasticsearch to compare (failing your deploy if there's a diff?)